# Request-promise-native not chaining 'then' as expected on working API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, protractor

Useage of 'request-native-promise' not correctly chaining to it's subsequent 'then' and 'catch' handlers.

**My Protractor Test**

```
    // There's a bunch of other imports here
    import { browser } from "protractor";
    const RequestPromise = require('request-promise-native');

    describe('spec mapper app', () => {
        let specMapperPage: SpecMapperPage;
        let specMapperFVRPage: SpecMapperFieldsValuesReviewPage;
        let loginLogoutWorkflow: LoginLogoutWorkflow;
        let apiToken: LoginToken;
        let tokenUtil: TokenUtil;
        let projectRecordsToBeDeleted = [];
        let requestHandler;
        let logger = new CustomLogger("spec mapper app");
        let speccyEndpoints = new SpeccyEndpoints();

        beforeAll( () => {
            logger.debug("Before All")
            loginLogoutWorkflow = new LoginLogoutWorkflow();
            loginLogoutWorkflow.login();
            tokenUtil = new TokenUtil();
            tokenUtil.getToken().then((token:LoginToken) => {
                apiToken = token;
                requestHandler = new SpeccyRequestHandler(apiToken);
            });
        });

        describe('import/export page', () => {

            it('TC2962: I'm a test case', () => {
                let testLogger = new CustomLogger("TC2955");
                // Test Var setup
                ... // removed for brevity

                // Test Setup
                browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
                // Setup the record to be on the mapper page
                let body = speccyEndpoints.generateRevitPostBody(PROJECT_ID, fileName);

                requestHandler.postToSpeccy(speccyEndpoints.DELITE_REVIT_POST_URI, body).then((response) => { // EDIT: removed non-existant argument "rejection"
                    // --> The then handler the promise is STILL not resolving into
                    // Only made it here like once
                    console.log("Response is: ");
                    console.log(response);

                    // I got this to work once, but now it's not
                    console.log("Response body is: ");
                    console.log(response.body);
                }).catch(error => {
                    // --> The catch handler is ALSO NOT resolving
                    console.log("catch handler executed!");
                    console.log(error);
                });        
            });
        });
    });
```

The test case where things are going wrong.  My `console.log("Response is: ");` is NOT being outputted. I'm not getting error messages as to why.

**My Speccy Request Handler Wrapper Class**

```
import * as RequestPromise from "request-promise-native";
import {LoginToken} from "../testObjects/LoginToken";
import {CustomLogger} from "../logging/CustomLogger";

export class SpeccyRequestHandler {

    _baseAPIURL = 'http://myapi.net/';
    _options = {
        method: '',
        uri: '',
        auth: {
            'bearer': ''
        },
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'client'
        },
        "resolveWithFullResponse": true,
        body: {},
        json: true
    };
    _logger;

    constructor(apiToken: LoginToken) {
        this._options.auth.bearer = apiToken.idToken;
        this._logger = new CustomLogger(SpeccyRequestHandler.name);
    }

    getOptions() {
        return this._options;
    }

    postToSpeccy(uri:string, body?) {
        this._options.method = 'POST';
        this._options.uri = this._baseAPIURL + uri;
        if(body) {
            this._options.body = body;
        }
        return RequestPromise(this._options);
    }

    getFromSpeccy(uri) {
        this._options.method = 'GET';
        this._options.uri = this._baseAPIURL + uri;
        return RequestPromise(this._options);
    }
}
```

This is my Request Handler specific to one of my APIs, the Speccy one, and has some custom aspects to it in the URL and the token passing.

**Sources**

[Request-Promise-Native Github Page](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native)
[Request-Promise Github page, documentation location](https://github.com/request/request-promise)

**Update Number 1**

After the fix @tomalak brought to my attention, my console.log's in the `.then(...` handler **were being** executed, the first 5-ish times after I changed over to this, I was getting a roughly 150+ line console log of the response object that contained a body of response I would expect from my request URI. I even got the body out by using `response.body`.  I thought things were fixed and I wasn't using my logger that logs out to file, so I lost my proof. Now when I run this test and this request I do not go into the `.then(...` handler at all. I'm also not going into the catch.  My request *is* working though, as my resource is created when the post endpoint is hit.  Any further suggestions are appreciated.

What would cause something to work sometimes and not others? My only thought is maybe the generic `post` name in my request handler wasn't being used in lieu of another method higher up the build chain being caught.

**Update Number 2**

Removed a bunch of stuff to shorten my question. If you need more clarification, ask and I'll add it.

Comment: `RequestPromise(options).then((response, reject) ...` - Hm, there are no `response` and `reject` arguments to the `.then()` callback...

Comment: I see what you mean! I was pushing that on it from my thoughts on Promise having resolve and reject. I went with just .then((response) ... and got an actual response! But my catch never caught that having the extra argument in the then was an issue and I never saw an error elsewhere.  Is there something I should do to to try to float these silent errors to the top where I can see them?  I appreciate the direction at the obvious!

Comment: That's a hard question. Other than using Typescript or something similar to track you down, I cannot recommend anything really (besides the obvious - failing and learning, of course - you won't make this error again I guess). I see many of these things because of experience, but not all of them by a long shot.

Comment: I'm using Typescript.  And still running into issues.  But definitely making some sort of progress. :) I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a timeout on the end of the API. My response was simply taking too long to get back to me. It wasn't failing, so it never went into the catch. And I had it working at one point because the response taking so long is due to an overabundance of a certain resource in our system in particular. I thought it was me and something I had written wrong. Long story short, suspect your system, even if you think it's perfect or if your devs swear up and down nothing could be broken.

Also, the request-debug module was a nice thing to have to prove that other endpoints, such as the rest testing endpoints at https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ , do work with your code.